# What is the MCU Red Guardian's origin?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

The history of the Red Guardian is ambiguous, due to his propensity for lying to both others and himself. He claims to have encountered Captain America, though much doubt is placed on this claim. Additionally, it can be difficult to tell the exact age of a super soldier.

How and when did he get his powers? Was it through a variant of Erskine's super soldier serum, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's really much out there on Alexei/Red Guardian yet and I haven't seen the film yet to know whether there's anything in there (though it doesn't look like it). However, the one thing I have found is a quote from David Harbour where he states the serum was developed in response to Captain America. There is also speculation that this is an improved upon version that was given to Bucky.

> He grew up in the Soviet Union during the arms race. He was a soldier. He was chosen for this program as the Americans were developing weapons and, of course, Captain America. The Russians were slow to catch up, but they wanted to fight back with their own version of Captain America. He was shot up with a super-strength serum and trained in a certain way. But he didn't become as famous as Captain America – nobody really knows who he is.
>
> <sub>[CinemaBlend, Black Widow’s David Harbour Discusses Red Guardian’s Captain America-Like Origins](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2559287/black-widows-david-harbour-discusses-red-guardians-captain-america-like-origins)</sub>

As this is a quote from the actor though it's always worth taking it with a pinch of salt until something more canonical comes along. This means it was likely another variant/copy cat of Erskine's formula like we see in *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*.